# STM32 Switching from standard peripheral to HAL. USB device always shows up as "Unknown Device" in windows

Tags: usb, stm32, hid

I have a project that needs to be compatible with STM32F1s and STM32F4s. I'm starting with a basic project that can use GPIOs and am now trying to get USB HID support. I have USB HID working on STM32F4s with another project using the standard peripheral drivers and USB OTG, but am having a difficult time with the HAL drivers. No matter what I've tried the USB device keeps showing up as an Unknown Device in windows. Where can I best start debugging this issue? Stepping through the code with  an SWD makes it seem like the board seems to be working as it should. As far as I can tell the endpoints and descriptors for HID are correct.

Comment: Besides SPL and HAL from dec 2015 exist LL - Low Level driver.

Answer (score 0):

Use STM32CubeMX to setup USB for you. Then you need to change the heap size, because the default one is not big enough. For some reason, you cannot change the heap size from STM32CubeMX. To change it, you need to edit the start up file (startup_stm32f4.....s) and find the line:

```
Heap_Size       EQU     0x00000200
```

and change the value to a bigger one, for example:

```
Heap_Size       EQU     0x00002000
```